# How to generate .key file from .cer to publish https:/// server

Tags: ssl

Please help me to share your knowledge and advice to convert `.cer` file to `.key` file for Apache as unable to start Apache services. Getting following error:

```
AH02579 : Init : Private key not found
SSL Library Error: error:0D0680a8:asn1 encoding :asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
```

Due to this I am unable to start Apache services.

Comment: Friends please help me

Answer (score 0):

Normally the key and the certificate are kept in separate files. If you believe the file you have contains both certificate and private key, see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/215606/how-do-i-view-the-details-of-a-digital-certificate-cer-file) for ways to determine if the key is there and to extract it.

Otherwise you will have to regenerate (or have regenerated) a new certificate and key pair.